# null value for all rows of a column!

Tags: mysql, database

Is there any way for setting all the rows of a column to a null value? thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell what you want without some context.  Are you saying you want a row in the database with all nulls?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about something simple like : `Update MyTable Set MyColumn = NULL`

Or, did you mean you wanted to set all columns in a row to NULL? If so, you have a database design problem. You should greatly limit what columns in a database accept NULL values.

Comment: I want all a column that all its rows are null

Answer (score 7):

Sure.

```
UPDATE table SET column = NULL
```

If you don't include a `WHERE` clause, the statement will affect all the rows in the table.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem like a basic question, but for efficiency reasons an update on all the rows of a column can take a very long time if it's a huge table.

There is a simple and efficient solution:
drop the column and add it again!